# Is Pietro Maximoff the son of Erik Lehnsherr?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

I know outside movie canon, Peter Maximoff, also known as QuickSilver, is the son of Magneto in comics. However, what about him in this "X-Men: Days of Future Past" and X-Men movies, is he the son of Magneto/Erik? While saving Eric, he didn't know that they seem to don't know each other. Although, he does says his mother once knew a guy who could control metal.

> Pietro Maximoff: They told me you control metal.
>
> Erik Lehnsherr: "They"?
>
> Pietro Maximoff: You know, my mom once knew a guy who could do that.

Is it only a joke in the movie or are the filmmakers implying that he is the son of Eric?

Comment: Actually, pietro isn't magnetos son anymore in the comics

Comment: Not even a mutant either.

Comment: Ohh, i thought this conflict occured for MCU only because they have sold rights to Mutants to Star

Comment: http://comicbook.com/2015/05/09/-scarlet-witch-quicksilvers-confirmed-as-not-being-mutants-true-/ its kind of an end run around the movie rights, but the current canon is that 616 Wanda and Pietro are genetic lab rats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *X-Men: Days of Future Past* it was considered just a joke / wink to the knowledgeable audience.

However, it was explicitly stated in *X-Men - Apocalypse* that Magneto was Quicksilver's father.

Edited Dialogue:

> Quicksilver: "Do you know him...Magneto?"
>
> Mystique: "Why do you care so much? You see his speech on TV or something?"
>
> Quicksilver: "Yeah, but...He's my father."
>
> Mystique: "What?"
>
> Quicksilver: "Him and my mom, they did it. Yeah. He left my mom before I was born. I met him 10 years back...but I didn't know it was him. By the time I figured it out,it was too late."

Comment: So, being same movie universe , he is son of Magneto in this movie also. Just they don't know that for now. I have not watched Apocalypse

Comment: A huge chunk of the resolution of the movie's story revolves around this being true.